# Angular 'property used before its initializadion' on @input object

Tags: angular

in my component i have a variable which is populated by the parent module, one of this variable's field 'description' should be displayed in the html template with a two way binding textarea so i can edit it:

```
   @Input() table: Table;
   public tableDescription: String = this.table.description (does not compile)
```

The above code wont compile, i get a `angular property is used before its initialization` error.
The way i am using that variable in the template is:

```
    <form class="form-table-description">
       <mat-form-field class="mat-table-description-input" appearance="fill">
       <textarea matInput style="resize: none;" rows="7" id="tableDescription" name="tableDescription" [(ngModel)]="tableDescription">{{tableDescription}}</textarea>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-button-toggle (click)="updateDescription()">Update description
</mat-button-toggle>
</form>
```

I have also tried to initialize that variable in `ngOnInit`:

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.tableDescription = this.table.description
    }
```

But although the code compiles i see:

- A warning stating that `arg1:TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'description')`
- The text area in the html template is empty.

How can i initialize the `tableDescription` variable in the component with the value of `table.description` and display it in the html template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move this assignment to at least `ngOnInit()` and the best would be `ngOnChanges` to react to input changes.

```
  @Input() table: Table;
   public tableDescription:string;

ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges){
   if(changes.table){
       this.tableDescription= this.table?.description;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: please read the entire question, i have already tried to put the assignment in ngOnInit but it does not work, i get a compiler warning.

Comment: Please read the answer again - it uses ngOnChanges

Comment: and TBH it should be an error not waring as it is literally NPE.\

Comment: it works Antoniosss, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to know when `@Input()` is changed to be sured you have `table` property set.

So this is better solution to `ngOnChanges`, it invokes only on `@Input` changed:

```
@Input set table(value: Table) {
  this.tableDescription = value?.description;
}
```